# Borell Cantelli Application

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

If i got that $\mathbb{P}(\underbrace{|X_{n}|>n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}}_{=:A_{n}})\leq \exp\left(-\frac{n^{2\epsilon}}{8}\right)$ with $\epsilon \in (0, 0.5)$.
I know that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb P(A_{n})\leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \exp\left(-\frac{n^{2\epsilon}}{8}\right)<\infty $. Thus $\mathbb P\left(\limsup A_{n}\right)=0$. But how is that limsup explicit in my case defined, and why does $X_{n}/n\rightarrow 0$ follows from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that there is a measurable subset $\Omega'\subset \Omega$ such that $\mathbb P(\Omega')=1$ and if $\omega\in\Omega$, then there exists $N(\omega)\in\mathbb N$ such that if $n\geqslant N(\omega)$, then $|X_n(\omega)|\leqslant n^{1/2+\varepsilon}$. 
This implies that for $n\geqslant N(\omega)$,
$$\frac1n|X_n(\omega)|\leqslant n^{\varepsilon-1/2}$$
and since $\varepsilon\lt 1/2$, 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)/n=0$. 
We prove that for each $\omega\in \Omega'$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)/n=0$ and the conclusion follows.